# ModRewrite to nice URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but I can't really find one that I can translate into what I need:

I'm trying to rewrite

```
www.domain.com/subfolder/index.php?p=test.php&condition=true&another=false
```

to

```
www.domain.com/subfolder/p/test/condition/true/another/false
```

where the PHP GET variables van be ints, strings or booleans. The p variable is special and will always be there.

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /subfolder/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

as a partial solution, but I can't get it to work (I just get 404s)

I'm a Mod Rewrite noob, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with regular expressions. If memory serves, you need something more like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/(.*)/(.*)/$ /subfolder/index.php?p=$1&condition=$2 [L]
```

Each numbered parameter must correspond to some piece of the first part of the rewrite. That is, the **$1** corresponds to the first **(.*)**.

I don't have time to test this, but the idea is more or less correct.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this, and it sill isn't working. I'm not sure if this is because it is rewritten to what is essentially a filename, test.php, which the server looks for, instead of passing to index.php. I'm certain ModRewrite works on this server as I have a WordPress install on the same server  that works fine.